# Why does CURL return error #7 when I try to access a web site?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to access a web site, which I can access through a browser but when I try accessing with PHP/CURL, I get

> Curl failed with error #7: Failed to connect to 140.113.207.51 port 8000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

My aim is to access the web site http://140.113.207.51:8000, passing it a web site name (in this case https://pubsonline.informs.org/journal/isre) and then to access the web site to process/parse the result.

Not sure whether I am approaching this in the right way, but I cannot get past the above error.

My code is:

```
$data = array('website' => urlencode('https://pubsonline.informs.org/journal/isre'));

try {

    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://140.113.207.51:8000',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

    // Check HTTP return code, too; might be something else than 200
    $httpReturnCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
    echo "HTTP Return Code: " . $httpReturnCode . "</br>";

    // Process $content here */

} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

} finally {
     //Close curl handle unless it failed to initialize
    if (is_resource($ch)) curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Given the 0ms and the fact that it works on my computer, I wonder if your network is not configured correctly on the machine you are trying to run this.

Comment: can you please check firewall state on this port

Comment: Thank you - I'll try. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I tried accessing the url but even Postman returns a 400 error, verify if the server is expecting a POST request

Comment: Thank you - I'll check